# Calling a javascript and opening a link

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to call a javascript and jump to a specified `div` by clicking on `Text`.
Here is the javascript I am using:

```
function hide(parameter) {
    document.getElementById(parameter).style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

and here the text that should call it:

```
<a id="text" href="Page.html#foo" href="javascript: hide('text')">Text Text</a>
```

I just don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ummm you cannot have 2 `href` attributes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a second href attribute to your a tag. Try onclick instead:

```
<a id="text" href="Page.html#foo" onclick="hide('text')">Text Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3155154's answer is the "best" way to do it, but, if you're interested, this will work too:

```
<a id="text" href="javascript:hide('text');window.location.href='Page.html#foo';void(0)">Text Text</a>
```